# How do I stop while loop from running infinitely?

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop

Can't figure out how to stop this while loop from repeating infinitely. I'm using `hasNextInt` to check if user input is an int. If an int is not entered the loop repeats infinitely.

```
public static void validatingInput(){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean valid = false;
    int userNumber = 0;

    while(!valid) { 
    System.out.println("Enter number between 1 and 20: ");

    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {    
    userNumber = scan.nextInt();
    valid = true;   
    } else 
        System.out.print("Not an int. ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to consume a token from a scanner in order to allow it to read the next token:

```
while (!valid) { 
    System.out.println("Enter number between 1 and 20: ");

    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {    
        userNumber = scan.nextInt();
        valid = true;   
    } else 
        System.out.print("Not an int. ");
        scan.next(); // Skip a token
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break any loops with `break;`.
Check the state of an input and break the while when you want