# How to terminate while loop on Q press in java console application

Tags: java

How can i terminate while loop when user press 'q' so program should exit?

It is Simple Java Program and i am not using swing etc.

```
while (flag) {

                int x = ran.nextInt(MaxValue - MinValue + 1);
                System.out.print(x);
                System.out.print(" enclosed by {");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(arr[i][0]);
                    if ((x >= arr[i][0]) && (x <= arr[i][1])) {
                        System.out.print("(" + arr[i][0] + "," + arr[i][1] + ")");
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("}\n");
                count++;
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop while loop from running infinitely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444997/how-do-i-stop-while-loop-from-running-infinitely)

Comment: @sayan I am looking for keypress and exit not to use scanner to get input..i hope you got it.

Comment: Just scan for the keypresses and compare with that of the letter 'q'. If it isn't then continue otherwise exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public void testFunction() {
        listener threadobj = new listener();//create the object
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadobj);//create the thread
        thread.start();//start the thread. it runs asynchronously

        while (flag /*assuming flag is unrelated*/ 
                && !threadobj.exit) {
            //when !threadobj.exit is false it means that q has been pressed.
            //so flag && !threadobj.exit will be false if at least one is false
            //so the loop will end
            int x = ran.nextInt(MaxValue - MinValue + 1);
            System.out.print(x);
            System.out.print(" enclosed by {");
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i][0]);
                if ((x >= arr[i][0]) && (x <= arr[i][1])) {
                    System.out.print("(" + arr[i][0] + "," + arr[i][1] + ")");
                }
            }
            System.out.print("}\n");
            count++;



        }

        threadobj.killMe = true;//finish its loop incase it is still running :)
    }
}
class listener implements Runnable {
    public boolean exit;    //if true then the q button has been pressed 
    public boolean killMe;  //set to true to kill this thread

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (!killMe) {           
            if(scanner.hasNext("q") || scanner.hasNext("Q")) { //Should trigger when a q is pressed.
                exit = true;        //if not use 'scanner.nextLine()'

                //wait a bit for input, so less cpu is used for constant checks.
                try {
                    this.wait(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }           
        }

    }

    public listener() {
        exit = false;
        killMe = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not close the `Scanner` when using `System.in`, you will find yourself unable to ever open `System.in` again, until the program is terminated.